# REST API - Node, Express, MySQL - How can I filter a JSON (from DB) return by passing a limited number of objects via URL

Tags: javascript, mysql, json, node.js, rest

I'm building a REST API, using Node, Express, MySQL.

When requesting a list of Node from the http://localhost:3000/Node endpoint,
I would like to limit these to only 25 initial records.
This could be accomplished with a request like GET http://localhost:3000/Node?maxRecords=25.

My routes\Nodes file is:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var Node=require('../models/Node');

router.get('/:id?',function(req,res,next){

    if(req.params.id){
        Node.getNodeById(req.params.id,function(err,rows){

            if(err)
            {
                res.json(err);
            }
            else{
                res.json(rows);
            }
        });
    }

    else{
        Node.getAllNodes(function(err,rows){

            if(err)
            {
                res.json(err);
            }
            else
            {
                res.json(rows);
            }
        });
    }
});
module.exports=router;
```

And in my models\Node.js (that is passing queries to db) is:

```
var db=require('../dbconnection');

var Node={

    getAllNodes:function(callback){

        return db.query("Select * from node_link",callback);

    },
    getNodeById:function(id,callback){

        return db.query("select * from node_link where id=?",[id],callback);
    }

}
module.exports=Node;
```

Answer (score 3):

In your models/Node.js:

```
getAllNodes: function(maxRecords, callback) {

  return db.query("Select * from node_link LIMIT ?", [maxRecords], callback);

}
```

Comment: Hi Grigory, is happening this problem now if I put limit:   throw err; // Rethrow non-MySQL errors
        ^

TypeError: val.slice is not a function

Comment: Have you updated your routes\Nodes file?

you must add param here:
`Node.getAllNodes(yourLimitParam, function(err,rows) { ... } )`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `LIMIT` in the query.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-limit.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The `LIMIT` attribute in your query will help, it will limit the number of rows outputted.
So, with this in mind, your query should look like:

```
SELECT * FROM node_link LIMIT 10
```

If you want more rows, just increase the `10` by whatever you want .

Comment: Hi Arthur is works but I would like to pass the limit via URL Example: http://localhost:3000/Node?maxRecords=25. where 25 is the array : [] named maxRecords

Comment: @SilvioCustodio Ok, then instead of 10, put `parseInt(maxRecords)`